# Kendo binding. View is not updating when changing the viewmodel

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-observable

For some reason beyond me, my view doesn't get updated when changing the viewmodel. What am I doing wrong here?

It displayes:
Test1 100
Test2 200

When I expect:
Test1 300
Test2 400

Javascript:

```
var testModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
    fields: {
        "Name": {
            type: "text"
        },
        "Amount": {
            type: "number"
        }
    }
});

testViewModel = new kendo.observable({
    Data: [
        new testModel({ "Name": "Test1", "Amount": 100 }),
        new testModel({ "Name": "Test2", "Amount": 200 })
    ]
});

kendo.bind("#test", testViewModel.Data);
var data = testViewModel.Data;
data[0].Amount = 300;
data[1].Amount = 400;
testViewModel.set("Data", data);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test" data-bind="source: Data" data-template="testTemplate"></div>
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Amount"></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to set a trigger to update the template, after updating the viewmodel.
Like this:

```
testViewModel.Data.trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing stufs a bit. You dont need to define a Model nor trigger the change event.
First initialize observable object:

```
var testViewModel = new kendo.observable({
    data: [
        { "Name": "Test1", "Amount": 100 },
        { "Name": "Test2", "Amount": 200 }
    ]
});
```

....bind it:

```
kendo.bind("#test", testViewModel.Data);
```

...change data:

```
testViewModel.data[0].set("Amount", 3000);
```

... HTML, check what `data-template` have and what `script` have:

```
<div id="test">
  <div data-bind="source: data" data-template="testTemplate"></div>
  <script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <div>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Amount"></span>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

that's it!.

```
<div id="test">
  <div data-bind="source: data" data-template="testTemplate">
   
  </div>
  <script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <div>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Amount"></span>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>

<script>
   var testViewModel = new kendo.observable({
        data: [
            { "Name": "Test1", "Amount": 100 },
            { "Name": "Test2", "Amount": 200 }
        ]
    });
  
    kendo.bind($("#test"), testViewModel);
    
    testViewModel.data[0].set("Amount", 3000);

</script>
```

Working example: [Observable binding](https://dojo.telerik.com/eboSihUm)

Check how to use observable object: [Observable object](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject)